# Copy files from one folder to another folder with filters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cp

I have these files in my source folder

```
source_path/date=20191230/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20191231/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20200101/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20200102/somefile.txt
```

If I do the bellow command all files will be copied to my dest_path folder

```
cp --recursive source_path/ dest_path/
```

I just want to copy all folders where dates are in 2020 or something

I just need these to files of 2020

```
source_path/date=20200101/somefile.txt
source_path/date=20200102/somefile.txt
```

How can I add filters with `cp` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not suitable for Stack Overflow, but this is the answer:

```
cp --recursive source_path/date=20200* dest_path/
```

Or does dest_path not exist? Then you would write

```
mkdir -p dest_path && cp --recursive source_path/date=20200* dest_path/
```

Comment: Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Answer (score 1):

You can use find with the -name, -type and -exec flags and so if the source directory was /home/foo and the destination directory /tmp:

```
find /home/foo -type d -name "*date-2020*" -exec cp '{}' /tmp \;
```

-type signifies that we only searching directories, -name is the name we are searching for and exec for command we are executing with the results